# Как сделать, чтобы скрипт открывал страницу?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Как сделать, чтобы приложенный скрипт перенаправлял пользователя на сформированную страницу сразу, когда выбрано три чекбокса?

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const obj = {
  a: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  b: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  c: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
}

inputs.forEach(addListener);

function addListener(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
}

function onClickHandler(e) {
  changeObjectValues(obj[e.target.name], e.target.value, true);
  const checkedInputs = getСlosestCheckedInputs(e.target);

  if (checkedInputs.length > 0) uncheckInputs(checkedInputs);

  if (isAllChecked()) {
    const url = 'https://site.ru' + Object.keys(obj).map(getPath).join('');
    alert(url);
  }
}

function getPath(key) {
  return obj[key].path;
}

function isAllChecked() {
  return Object.keys(obj).every(isChecked);
}

function isChecked(key) {
  return obj[key].isChecked === true;
}

function changeObjectValues(obj, path, isChecked) {
  obj.path = path;
  obj.isChecked = isChecked;
}

function getСlosestCheckedInputs(target) {
  const inputs = target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const checkedInputs = [];

  inputs.forEach(function getCheckedInput(input) {
    if (input.checked && input != target) checkedInputs.push(input);
  });

  return checkedInputs;
}

function uncheckInputs(checkedInputs) {
  checkedInputs.forEach(function uncheck(input) {
    input.checked = false;
  })
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.a>.row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.b>.row {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.c>.row {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<!-- A -->
<div class="a container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="a-1" type="checkbox" value="/a-1/" name="a">
    <label for="a-1">a 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input id="a-2" type="checkbox" value="/a-2/" name="a">
    <label for="a-2">a 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- B -->
<div class="b container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="b-1" type="radio" value="b-1/" name="b">
    <label for="b-1">b 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input id="b-2" type="radio" value="b-2/" name="b">
    <label for="b-2">b 2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- C -->
<div class="c container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="c-1" type="checkbox" value="c-1" name="c">
    <label for="c-1">c 1</label>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input id="c-2" type="checkbox" value="c-2" name="c">
    <label for="c-2">c 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const obj = {
  a: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  b: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
  c: {
    path: '',
    isChecked: false
  },
}

inputs.forEach(addListener);

function addListener(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
}

function onClickHandler(e) {
  changeObjectValues(obj[e.target.name], e.target.value, true);
  const checkedInputs = getСlosestCheckedInputs(e.target);

  if (checkedInputs.length > 0) uncheckInputs(checkedInputs);

  if (isAllChecked()) {
    const url = 'https://len-service-support.ru/' + Object.keys(obj).map(getPath).join('');
    location.href = url;
  }
}

function getPath(key) {
  return obj[key].path;
}

function isAllChecked() {
  return Object.keys(obj).every(isChecked);
}

function isChecked(key) {
  return obj[key].isChecked === true;
}

function changeObjectValues(obj, path, isChecked) {
  obj.path = path;
  obj.isChecked = isChecked;
}

function getСlosestCheckedInputs(target) {
  const inputs = target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const checkedInputs = [];

  inputs.forEach(function getCheckedInput(input) {
    if (input.checked && input != target) checkedInputs.push(input);
  });

  return checkedInputs;
}

function uncheckInputs(checkedInputs) {
  checkedInputs.forEach(function uncheck(input) {
    input.checked = false;
  })
}
```